# How to get ad spend at content level for Google Shopping campaigns?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client, google-shopping-api

I can get ad spend for each campaign using googleapis. But how to get ad spend at the content level for Google shopping campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get ad spend at content level (offerId or shopping item id) for shopping campaign using Google Analytics. I tried hacking google analytics request to see how they could display in the dashboard. Figured out that there is a dimension called ga:shoppingItemId which is not exposed to the outer world.

have to use Google Adwords API to get this done.

Follow https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/shopping-performance-report

to get metrics for shopping campaigns. Very lengthy process though.